# Regular expression for email not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I am putting validation on email field but it shows error of invalid even where the email is typed in correct format.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su9nZ.jpg)

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formvalidate(){
    var email=document.signup_form.email.value;

    var check_email= RegExp("^[A-Z0-9._-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z0-9.-]+$");

    if(email=="")
    {
        alert("cannot be empty!");
        document.signup_form.email.focus();
        return false;
    }

    else if(!check_email.test(email))
    {
        alert("enter valid email address!");
        document.signup_form.email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your regex only accepts capital letters.

Comment: By your regex `-@-.-`/`.@...` are valid emails

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

1- Use this regular expressions instead

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

2- Change this `if (!check_email.test(email))` to

```
if (check_email.test(email))
```

Comment: I used this expression but still shows invalid error on valid email (firstname@gmail.com)

Answer (score 1):

try this function

```
function validateEmail(elementValue) {
    var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    return emailPattern.test(elementValue);
}
```

Please refer this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/Ra85j/

Answer (score 0):

Try this fuction

```
     function isEmail(inputString) {
     var regExpEmail = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
         try {
              return regExpEmail.test(inputString.value);
             }
        catch (e) {
              return false;
               }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change `var check_email= RegExp("^[A-Z0-9._-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z0-9.-]+$");` to 
a function like this:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You regex is not correct, there are many things that you've not considered, like your regex accepts only capital letters, to include both capital and small letters you should use :

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

not this :

```
[A-Z0-9]
```

You can use this regex for validating email :

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript) for details

Answer (score 0):

[Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) and some [tests](https://regex101.com/r/xX7uR4/1)

You can use this regex for email:

```
RegExp('\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b', 'i')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this example : `email validation using JQuery`

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

function validate() {
  $("#emailvalidate").text("");
  var email = $("#email").val();
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $("#emailvalidate").text(email + " is valid");
    $("#emailvalidate").css("color", "green");
  } else {
    $("#emailvalidate").text(email + " is not valid");
    $("#emailvalidate").css("color", "red");
  }
  return false;
}
$("form").bind("submit", validate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <p>Enter an email address:</p>
  <input id='email'>
  <button type='submit' id='btn'>Validate</button>
</form>
<h2 id='emailvalidate'></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```js
function formvalidate()
{
    var email = document.signup_form.email.value;

    var check_email = RegExp("^([a-z0-9\\+_\\-]+)(\\.[a-z0-9\\+_\\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\\-]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$", 'ig');

    if(email == "")
    {
        alert("cannot be empty!");
        document.signup_form.email.focus();
        return false;
    }

    else if(!check_email.test(email))
    {
        alert("enter valid email address!");
        document.signup_form.email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="signup_form">
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
  <input type="button" name="validate" value="Validate" onclick="formvalidate()"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using below regex to validate email pattern. Regex is not 100% solution to validate an email, better use email verification. Regex can help to validate format or pattern only.

**`Jsfiddle`**: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/neerajsinghsonu/bqngtp5u/)

**`Jsfiddle`**: Regex check and sample email [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/neerajsinghsonu/d1uzr75k/2/)

```js
function validateEmail(elementValue) {
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = elementValue + ', email is incorrect';
  var emailPattern = /^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]+\.)*(?!.*(?:__|\\.\\.))[a-z0-9_]+@(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?!\.)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?!$)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]?)|(?:(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])))$/;
  if (emailPattern.test(elementValue)) {
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = elementValue + ', email is correct';
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
#error {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

input[type='email'] {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  border-color: blue;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<form name="signup_form">
  <input type="email" value="" onblur="validateEmail(this.value)">
  <br />
  <lable id="error"></lable>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your regular expression to below

`^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$`

Hope this helps :)